# Array sum of just on key with multiple values

Tags: php

I have the following array.

The `print_r` of `$MyArray`

```
Array ( [0] => 7,8,9,8,7)
```

How can I get the sum of all this numbers? At this example, I want to get "**39**".

`array_sum($MyArray)` is not working for me (because it's just one key, if I am right?)

.

**I found the solution** (if someone also has this problem):

1. Restructure the array with `$MyArray = explode(',', $MyArray);` so that every value, separated by a comma, gets its own key.
2. Then just use `array_sum($MyArray)`

Comment: Array_sum() documentation says it calculates the sum of array values. The value is not a number. Also the sum of the keys would be 0.

Comment: Why do you put the answer into the question?

Answer (score 0):

As per you array output, you first need to use index zero get that numbers data.After that you can conver that to array and then use sum function.
Here is updated code.

```
 $numbersArray = explode(",", $MyArray[0]);
 array_sum($numbersArray);
```